# Requesting data from WCF Webservice with Qooxdoo

Tags: wcf, soap, qooxdoo

I have a qooxdoo web application which should be able to request data from a WCF web service. The WCF service uses SOAP. I'm currently looking for a way to set up the communication between my qooxdoo application and the WCF web service.

Is there a way to get this done? I saw that qooxdoo is supporting REST and I'm looking for something like a SOAP module in qooxdoo.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's an ancient contrib, probably unmaintained, at http://svn.code.sf.net/p/qooxdoo-contrib/code/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/Soap/0.5.1/. You might not be able to use it right away, but I think the source code there will need just a few changes to become usable.